# Second largest integer without .sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def second_largest(numbers):
    first = 0
    second = 0
    for n in numbers:
        if n > first:
            first, second = n, first
        elif first > n > second:
            second = n
    return second or None
print(second_largest([2,2,2,-2]))
```

When i run this code, output is `None`, but i need it to be `-2` and also i cant use functions as .sorted and others for array. I think that problem is in `second = 0` ,but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you use the built-in `max()` function?

Comment: it says i cant modify input array so i am not sure

Comment: Use `elif n > second` in place of `elif first > n > second`.

Comment: In that case, since it doesn't, using it should be OK.

Comment: Instead of `first = 0` and `second = 0`, you should set them both to the smallest value supported by their datatype (e.g. -65536 for `short`s)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a few issues I see.

1. You are instantiating `first` and `second` incorrectly (what if the largest number is negative)?
2. The only time you'd want to return None is if your list size is smaller than 2.
3. Change your return condition to `return second`.

```
def second_largest(numbers):
    if len(numbers) < 2:
        return None

    first, second = numbers[0], numbers[1]
    if first < second:
        first, second = second, first

    for n in numbers[2:]:
        if n > first:
            first, second = n, first
        elif n > second:
            second = n

    return second
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can basically take the largest element out of the list (or make a note of it) and then search for the second-largest element in what's left. Here, I do this by first using `max()` (a built-in function of python that works on any iterable object) to get the largest element of the list, then using a list comprehension to create a second list of elements that do not equal that largest element, and finally using `max()` again to get the second-largest element from the original list.

```
def second_largest(numbers):
    first = max(numbers)
    second = max([i for i in numbers if i != first])
    return second
```

You could use a `for` loop for this if you didn't want to use `max()` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided does not handle cases where `n == first`.  Changing `elif first > n > second` to `elif n > second` should be sufficient (you do not need to test if `first >= n` since if control can reach that line `n > first` must be false).

Answer (score 0):

Not use `sorted`?

```
values = [2,2,2,-2]
values.sort(reverse=True)   # technically correct
second_largest = values[1]
```

or, less facetious

```
values = set([2,2,2,-2])
values.remove(max(values))
second_largest = max(values)
```

Or even

```
import heapq
heapq.nlargest(2, [2,2,2,-2])
```

Comment: It was not clear to me that this is homework. If someone is googling this problem and exclusively gets homework solutions rather than, say, `heapq` then they're going to have a sad time.

Answer (score 0):

```
def second_largest(numbers):
    if len(numbers) < 2:
        return "less than 2 numbers"
    

    temp1,temp2 = numbers[0], numbers[1]

    if temp1 < temp2:
        temp1, temp2 = temp2, temp1


    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] > temp2:
            if numbers[i] > temp1:
                temp2 = temp1
                temp1 = numbers[i]
            else:
                temp2 = numbers[i]
        else:
            if(temp1==temp2):
                temp2 = numbers[i]
    return temp2
```